# Do these two primate characters come from their own game?

Tags: game-identification, poker-night-2

I've always wondered whenever I play Poker Night 2 where these two gorilla characters come from.

[image]

[image]

**Do these two come from their own game/series?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These character appear as villains in Telltale Games' new(ish) [Sam & Max -series](https://telltale.com/series/sam-and-max-season-three/).
Specifically the 3rd season, *The Devil's Playhouse*, 1st episode, *The Penal Zone*, where

> Intergalactic gorilla invader Skunk'ape sets his sights on unhinged
> rabbit Max.

The one in the car is the above mentioned Skun'ape, and the other one is one of his minions.